# Method for common values in two lists

Tags: ruby, intersection

Does Ruby has a method I could use when I have 2 arrays (lists) and I want to get an array (list) of only the values common to both arrays? Like this..

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [3,4,5]
=> the method would return [3]
```

And the other way around, values that are "unique" in those arrays (lists).

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [3,4,5]
=> the method would return [1,2,4,5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AND : a & b
```

There are no XOR method for arrays in Ruby, so you may do it via another methods. Here are 2 ways:

```
XOR : (a | b) - (a & b)
XOR : (a + b) - (a & b) # this result can have duplicates!

XOR : (a - b) | (b - a)
XOR : (a - b) + (b - a) # this result can have duplicates!
```

Comment: Wouldn't that really be 2 ways then? :)

Answer (score 2):

The words you are looking for are **intersection** and **symmetric difference**. AFAIK it's this in Ruby:

```
[1,2,3] & [3,4,5] = [3]
[1,2,3] ^ [3,4,5] = [1,2,4,5]
```

Comment: ^ only works on sets. You could, however, write `(Set[1,2,3]^Set[3,4,5]).to_a`

Comment: aka (array1.to_set ^ array2.to_set).to_a